# Autotab contenteditable divs or adding function to input type: text

Tags: javascript, html, events, contenteditable

I have 3 contenteditable divs.  The first and third divs have a function that simulates changing the character associated with a key event, typing out a pre-programmed string as the user types, and the second div is straightforward- what the user types appears in the div.  This can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/vRXph/4/.  I've included the code for the first div here for convenience:

```
var list1 = "Sing in me, Muse, and through me tell the story".replace(/\s/g,
 "\xA0").split("")
function transformTypedCharacter1(charStr) {
    var position = $("#verse1").text().length;
    if (position >= list1.length) return '';
    else return list1[position];
}

function insertTextAtCursor1(text) {
    var sel, range, textNode;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.deleteContents();
            textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
            range.insertNode(textNode);

            // Move caret to the end of the newly inserted text node
            range.setStart(textNode, textNode.length);
            range.setEnd(textNode, textNode.length);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.pasteHTML(text);
    }
}


$("#verse1").keypress(function(evt) {
    if (evt.which) {
        var charStr = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
        var transformedChar = transformTypedCharacter1(charStr);
        if (transformedChar != charStr) {
            insertTextAtCursor1(transformedChar);
            evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I want to autotab between these divs.  In the first div, the autotab function would be called after the final pre-programmed character is typed, and for the second div the autotab would be called after a certain number of characters (lets say 5 characters, just to keep it short as a test).

My first question (of 3): How do I autotab between contenteditable divs?
I have found a way to autotab between input type: text fields here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ukkmu/73/ but I cannot seem to apply this to my divs.  I attempted, and failed, to do this here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ukkmu/76/.

```
    function auTab (currentDiv, currentDivSize, currentDivLength, nextDiv) {
    if(currentDivSize == currentDivLength){
        $('#' + currentDiv).next().focus();
    };
};

$('div[id^="verse"]').keyup(function() {
    var thisDiv = $(this).attr('id');
    var thisDivSize = $(this).attr('size');
    var thisDivLength = $(this).val().length;

    auTab(thisDiv, thisDivSize, thisDivLength);
});
```

As you can see, the system just ignores the autotab function.  I created a size of "5" on my first div as a test.  I don't know if this is possible, but I did it because I saw that the autotab function is dependent on size.  My second question (of 3) is: Can I assign a size or maxlength attribute to a contenteditable div?  If I can, and if the autotabbing relies on this attribute, then I would simply assign the size of the first div to be the number of characters in my pre-programmed string (and for the second div I would assign 5 characters as test, as I mentioned above).

An alternative would be to change my contenteditable divs to input type: text fields.  I did this here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ukkmu/74/, but as you can see my original function that I described in the first paragraph of this question no longer works.  I end up with a repeated character (the "S" from my pre-programmed string) *before* the first field, instead of my pre-programmed string *in* the first field.  For this test I put the size of the field as 3, just as a test.  The final version would be the size of the entire pre-programmed string.  My 3rd question (of 3), if applicable: How can I apply the function that simulates changing the character associated with a key even to input type= text fields?

My application of this code is that this is an art project.  As the user types, the output on the screen alternates between a classic text (in this case, Homer's *The Odyssey*), and what the user is actually typing.

Sorry if this is a very long post, but I wanted to include as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, thanks to pckill, answers question 3.  I used input type: text fields with the following function:

```
var list1 = "This is a test.".replace(/\s/g, "\xA0").split("")
function transformTypedChar1(charStr) {
    var position = $("#verse1").val().length;
    if (position >= list1.length) return '';
    else return list1[position];
}
```